# Detect if the load is present on this circuit

Tags: triac, dimmer, optoelectronics

[image]

Is there a way to detect if the load is conected on the circuit above?
(The other load should be connected to the F Pad, sorry for the mistake).

Comment: Put a resistor in series with the output, check if there is a voltage across it.

Comment: Are you sure that both LOAD terminals should be connected to the N terminal ... ?

Comment: You are right, one is connected to the F pad

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLaUNU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Current indicator.*

Something like this may work depending on your load current. The diode bridge will drop about 1.4 V at a reasonable current and this should be enough to light an infrared LED as found in an opto-coupler. I've shown two arranged back to back so that a pulse could be detected on each half-cycle.

I have not tried it.

[image]

*Figure 2. A current transformer and indicator lamp.*

Devices such as that in Figure 2 are a safer means of accomplishing the task. In this case the visible LED can be replaced by an opto-isolator LED but get a back-to-back type or put a reverse diode in parallel so that there is a current path on both half-cycles.

The othe